# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named EclipseLink_JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have building databases with JPA before but suddenly my project doesnt work and I cant figure out what has happened. Keed getting this errormessage:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No
>   Persistence provider for EntityManager named EclipseLink_JPA  at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:84)
>     at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="EclipseLink_JPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>Entity.Person</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/persons"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="theUser"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="myPassword"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And try to call:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EclipseLink_JPA");
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
```

It used to work perfectly fine but suddenly I only getting the errormessage.

Comment: are you sure that eclipselink is in the path?

Comment: Check that your persistence.xml is on your path. It should also likely include <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> to specify which JPA provider should load the persistence unit.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved removing eclipse-link-3.0.0 and re-inserting eclipse-link- 2.5.2 in the pom.xml

Eclipse use this version to generate entity from tables

Answer (score 0):

Try to add provider inside persistence unit. I haven't ever worked with EclipseLink so I don't know its package name.

```
<persistence-unit ... >
    <provider>
        org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider  <!-- Replace this with EclipseLink package-->
    </provider>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```